# How EOF really works in this one?

Tags: c, eof

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main() {
    long nc;
    nc = 0;

    while (getchar()!= EOF){
        ++nc;
        printf("%ld\n", nc);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: When I input a number or a character, it increments twice >.<
for example: I ran the program, I typed 1, then its going to output

```
1
2
```

can someone please tell me why >< cause isn't it suppose to just increment 1? And the value of `nc` that the program is gonna show is 1? Then its going to become 2 when i enter another number or character?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you don't need to write in all caps.

Comment: The enter-key is taken as the 2nd character.

Comment: As a suggestion, you can use a debugger like `gdb` and step through your program to check the intermediate values. That will give you a clear picture.

Answer (score 1):

After entering any number you are pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
and as `'\n' != EOF`  so it is running two times.

```
int main() {
long nc;
nc = 0;
    while (getchar()!= '\n'){ // check for enter key here.
      ++nc;
      printf("%ld\n", nc);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check if the char is `!= '\r'` as well? This won't work on Mac and will be bugged on linux. Then again so will the printf....

Answer (score 1):

When you input a number and press `Enter` key, an additional `\n` character passed to the standard input buffer. `getchar` reads that number leaving behind \n in the buffer. On next iteration of loop getchar reads `\n` before pressing any character by you and hence inside while for second time.Hence value is printed twice as `\n` is not there.

Use below while condition and this shall fix the issue.

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

This will eat up any number of \n.